# Ionic2 / Angular 2 Platform import

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angular, ionic2

I am trying to learn ag2 with ionic 2 and trying most simple things.

I am trying to import platform and get necessary details iin my ionic 2 app.

I followed http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform/

import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';

```
@Component({...})
export MyPage {
  constructor(platform: Platform) {
    this.platform = platform;
  }
}
```

My code -

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
    import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';

    @Component({
      templateUrl: 'build/pages/items-map/items-map.html'
    })
    export class ItemsMap {

      constructor(platform: Platform) {
          this.platform = platform;
     }

btainNetworkConnection() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.networkState = navigator.connection.type;

        var states = {};
        states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
        states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
        states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
        states[Connection.CELL]     = 'Cell generic connection';
        states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

        alert('Connection type: ' + states[this.networkState]);
    });
  }

    }
```

NOw I am trying to build the codebase by gulp build and getting following output -

```
[00:06:26] Using gulpfile ~/Documents/Projects/Ionic2_1/MyIonic2Project/gulpfile.js
[00:06:26] Starting 'clean'...
[00:06:26] Finished 'clean' after 14 ms
[00:06:26] Starting 'build'...
[00:06:26] Starting 'sass'...
[00:06:26] Starting 'html'...
[00:06:26] Starting 'fonts'...
[00:06:26] Starting 'scripts'...
[00:06:26] Finished 'html' after 45 ms
[00:06:26] Finished 'scripts' after 43 ms
[00:06:26] Finished 'fonts' after 48 ms
[00:06:26] Finished 'sass' after 637 ms
TypeScript error: /Users/kray/Documents/Projects/Ionic2_1/MyIonic2Project/app/pages/item-map/items-map.ts(10,12): Error TS2339: Property 'platform' does not exist on type 'ItemsMap'.
[00:06:28] Finished 'build' after 2.28 s
```

I am getting a feeling that I am missing something basic here which I am not sure.

I also checked node_modules for platform related typescript files and they are present. Snapshot -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the variable platform in your Item map.

```
export class ItemsMap {

platform:Platform//my addition
  constructor(platform: Platform) {
      this.platform = platform;
 }

}
```

Or use typescript in build constructor shortcut to declare property like

```
export class ItemsMap {

    //notice modifier on constructor 
      constructor(public platform: Platform){

     }

    }
```

You can see more info on Typescript class [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html)

Answer (score 0):

The private/public word is mandatory in the constructor when using Typescript:

```
constructor(private platform: Platform) {
      //...
 }
```

Also, you don't need to include the

```
this.platform = platform;
```

Because by just adding `private platform : Platform` in your constructor, that brief syntax does a lot:

- Declares a constructor parameter and its type
- Declares a private property of the same name
- Initializes that property with the
  corresponding argument when we "new" an instance of the class

Comment: Thanks for the details. I understood it but my concern is with most of the vars like "navigator" which does not seem to be working during build, same for this.networkState. I am confused around is it something that needs to be defined around imports or with local vars and how to identify. Thanks for the help

Comment: That's something different. I would recommend you to create a new question with that, because  `Platform` is part of Ionic 2 framework, but the `navigator` property is part of the [cordova-plugin-network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information), so the answer would be different.